# How do I use checkbutton on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have this code, and i try everything and the checkbutton is not show the password, what's the error??
I'm new to tkinter and I'm trying to make this login screen, however the checkbutton is not working i try everything and the checkbutton is not show the password, what's the error??????????????????????????????????????

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class RegisterScreen():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.windowRegister()
        self.window_frameRegister()
        self.widget_frameRegister()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def windowRegister(self):
        self.root.title("Bom de Prato")
        self.root.geometry("800x600")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.root["bg"] = "purple"

    def window_frameRegister(self):
        self.frame = Frame(self.root, bd=4)

        self.frame.place(relx=0.17, rely=0.10, relwidth=0.65, relheight=0.80)

    def widget_frameRegister(self):
        # Create Label
        self.lb_register = Label(self.frame, text='Register', font='impact 40 bold')
        self.lb_login = Label(self.frame, text='User', font='arial 20')
        self.lb_password = Label(self.frame, text="Password", font='arial 20')
        self.lb_email = Label(self.frame, text='Email', font='arial 20')

        self.user_entry = Entry(self.frame)
        self.password_entry = Entry(self.frame, show="*")
        self.email_entry = Entry(self.frame)

        self.lb_register.place(relx=0.32, rely=0.05)
        self.lb_login.place(relx=0.41, rely=0.25)
        self.lb_password.place(relx=0.37, rely=0.40)
        self.lb_email.place(relx=0.41, rely=0.55)
        self.user_entry.place(relx=0.24, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.50)
        self.password_entry.place(relx=0.24, rely=0.50, relwidth=0.50)
        self.email_entry.place(relx=0.24, rely=0.65, relwidth=0.50)

        # Create Button
        self.btn_register = Button(self.frame, text='register', font="arial 20")
        self.btn_register.place(relx=0.38, rely=0.75, relwidth=0.22, relheight=0.15)

        # Checkbutton
        self.check_var = IntVar()
        self.check_show_psw = Checkbutton(self.frame, text='EYES', variable=self.check_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, height=2, width=5, command=self.show_hide_psd)
        self.check_show_psw.place(relx=0.78, rely=0.50, relwidth=0.10, relheight=0.05)

    def show_hide_psd(self):
        if self.check_var.get():
            self.password_entry.config(show="s")
        else:
            self.password_entry.config(show="*")


class SignInScreen():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.window()
        self.window_frame()
        self.widget_frame()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def window(self):
        self.root.title("Bom de Prato")
        self.root.geometry("800x600")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.root["bg"] = "purple"

    def window_frame(self):
        self.frame = Frame(self.root, bd=4)

        self.frame.place(relx=0.17, rely=0.10, relwidth=0.65, relheight=0.80)

    def widget_frame(self):
        # Create Label
        self.lb_bom_de_prato = Label(self.frame, text='Bom de Prato', font='impact 40 bold')
        self.lb_login = Label(self.frame, text='User', font='arial 20')
        self.lb_password = Label(self.frame, text="Password", font='arial 20')

        self.user_entry = Entry(self.frame)
        self.password_entry = Entry(self.frame, show='*')

        self.lb_bom_de_prato.place(relx=0.20, rely=0.05)
        self.lb_login.place(relx=0.41, rely=0.25)
        self.lb_password.place(relx=0.37, rely=0.40)
        self.user_entry.place(relx=0.24, rely=0.35, relwidth=0.50)
        self.password_entry.place(relx=0.24, rely=0.50, relwidth=0.50)

        # Create Button
        self.btn_login = Button(self.frame, text='Login', font="arial 20")
        self.btn_register = Button(self.frame, text='Register', font='arial 20', command=RegisterScreen)

        self.btn_login.place(relx=0.24, rely=0.60, relwidth=0.22, relheight=0.15)
        self.btn_register.place(relx=0.52, rely=0.60, relwidth=0.22, relheight=0.15)

SignInScreen()
```

Comment: Don't call `Tk()` more than once, you need to use `Toplevel()` instead to create additional windows.

Comment: Also, the imports `from tkinter import Tk` and `import tkinter as tk` are redundant.

Comment: THANKS MAN 
I APPRECIATE IT!

Comment: @jasonharper make that an answer so it can be marked correct